# How to find zip string is present in line of the file or not. if found extarct the zip file

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which is having files path. I am passing this files line by line to the script. I have to find zip file is there in files path. If it's present I have to extract the zip file. How can I do this? I have tried below code but not working.

File i am passing to the script:
zipfile:

```
    device/sprd/sharkle/common/bootanimation.zip/bootup/0467.png
    device/sprd/sharkle/common/bootanimation.zip/bootup/0567.png
    base/tests/TransitionTests/res/drawable-nodpi/self_portrait_square_400.jpg
    base/media/tests/contents/media_api/video/MPEG2_1500_AAC_128.mp4
    device/sprd/sharkle/common/image.zip/bootup/0367.png
    device/sprd/sharkle/common/tycho.zip/bootup/0195.png
    device/sprd/sharkle/sp9820e_2c10/modem_bins/ltemodem.bin/mtcd
```

Script:

```
#! /bin/bash
 file="zipfile"
 while IFS= read line;
 do

 if grep -q ".zip" $line ;
 then
#i have to extract zip file
 else
 echo not present
 fi   
done <"$file"
```

Comment: You set a variable _line_, but you never use it. To use the variable, you have to write it as `"$line"`.

Comment: Actually, I don't understand the logic behind your script. It seems that for each file mentioned in the file `zipfile`, you want to find out whether its 28th line contains the text `zip` at some place except the start of the line. I don't see how this is related to the task you describe in your question.

Comment: Also you write _file i am passing to the script_, but your script does not get **passed** any file (you don't access anywhere parameters to the script, nor environment variables, so there is no _passing_ of information).

Comment: Finally, you tag your question as _shell_, but you clearly present a _bash_ script. If you want to discuss a bash-specific solution, please add the _bash_ tag to your question.

Comment: i have misplaced part of the script. using grep i am checking zip string is there in  line of the file. if present extract that zip file. this is the logic.

Comment: You can trivially `unzip "$line"` but there are a number of corner cases to solve. What if several zip files contain the same file names? What if they are encrypted? Etc. I find it hard to believe that you did any search before asking here, as the basic `unzip` command shoud not be hard to discover.

Comment: My difficulty is not to unzip the file. I have find file path consist of zip string or not. if present i have to grep zip file name and unzip the archive.

Comment: $line is not zip file name. Its file path. I can't use unzip $line

Comment: Why do you think you can't? What happens if you do?

Comment: $ unzip path/to/file/bootanimation.zip/dllfile
unzip:  cannot find or open path/to/file/bootanimation.zip/dllfile, path/to/file/bootanimation.zip/dllfile.zip or path/to/file/bootanimation.zip/dllfile.ZIP.
I am trying by passing one line of the file. but getting above error

Answer (score 0):

Slice the path using Parameter Expansion and use associative array to avoid duplicates.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file=zipfile

declare -A zipfiles

while IFS= read -r line; do
  if [[ $line == *".zip/"* ]]; then
    to_remove=${line##*.zip}
    line=${line%"$to_remove"}
    ((zipfiles["$line"]++))
  else                              
    printf >&2 'No zip file at %s\n' "$line"
  fi
done < "$file"

for item in "${!zipfiles[@]}"; do
  echo unzip "$item"
done
```

Output of the script from your sample file.

```
No zip file at base/tests/TransitionTests/res/drawable-nodpi/self_portrait_square_400.jpg
No zip file at base/media/tests/contents/media_api/video/MPEG2_1500_AAC_128.mp4
No zip file at device/sprd/sharkle/sp9820e_2c10/modem_bins/ltemodem.bin/mtcd
unzip device/sprd/sharkle/common/image.zip
unzip device/sprd/sharkle/common/tycho.zip
unzip device/sprd/sharkle/common/bootanimation.zip
```

- As what mentioned in the comments by @tripleee, there are cases that this will fail, or will not work as expected.
- Needs more testing / error checking but feel free to adjust the code.
- Remove the `echo` (and add more `uzip` option if need be) if you're satisfied with the output.
- Taking an educated guess from the file you posted it looks like it is coming from find's output.

Comment: Since we have bash, I think it should be `to_remove="${line##*.zip}"`, as the path to the file may contain spaces.

Comment: @user1934428, there is no word splitting being performed during the assignment so the quotes are not needed even if the variable contains spaces, but the quotes does not hurt as well. also it is a good habit to quotes them variables.